# Install LESS compiler and setup bootstrap workflow in Ubuntu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, less, ubuntu-14.04

I am a php developer and have not done much front-end work for 3 or 4 years so I feel its time to update my skill set. I want to install a less compiler and set-up a bootstrap work flow using my Ubuntu desktop. I know how to use the basic pre-compiled bootstrap but I’m kinda lost with all this LESS stuff. I need to use it as I want to shoehorn bootstrap onto an existing application that has all its own css classes in the html output that cant really be changed easily. So Ill need to extend the LESS files to add these classes to the boostrap css.

I am just not sure where to start. Does anybody know of tutorial that will walk me through installing and setting up the LESS complier then how to use it so that I can work in an efficient way. Iv searched but can really find any Ubuntu specific or up to date tuts.

Comment: got lessc installed and working just not sure how work with complling the whole of bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For installing less, you can use lessc:

it is a node.js package which convert less to css, with several options:

> http://lesscss.org/#using-less-installation

You need to install npm before

Full installation:

```
# apt-get install npm
# npm install -g less
```

And to use, as explained in the doc, just use lessc package.

For me, when I work with less, I use Bracket editor: http://brackets.io/

You can then install an extension which, when you save less file, automaticaly compile less to a css file: https://github.com/jdiehl/brackets-less-autocompile

(you find it with built-in extension manager)

Maybe for others IDE / editor, you have also plugins